# Videoview on splashscreen

Tags: android, eclipse, android-videoview, splash-screen

I'm making an app that starts with a splash screen. It includes a videoview, but when the app starts there is a black square until it loads the video. I tried to set a background to the videoview (same as the activity has - blue), but at this case the background hides the video.
How could I solve this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One recommendation would be to put a starting image(or a blank image/color) and them set

```
videoView.setOnPreparedListener
```

to hide that image once the video is ready.